# if the content in the label matches a cell in a row C#

Tags: c#

If the content in the label matches a cell content in 'column1' (the order ID column) of the database (similar concept to a login form), change value of cell 4 (the order location) in that specific row (and only that row) to specific value in textbox

```
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes) // When the button is clicked and the user selects yes.
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Customer Orders] WHERE [Order ID] = @OrderId", MAcon);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", OleDbType.Integer);

            //  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrderId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 2;
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtbl);

            if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Customer Orders] SET [OrderStatus] = (@OrderStatus), [OrderID]= @OrderId", MAcon); //SET[Order Status] = (@OrderStatus)

                MAcon.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", orderID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderStatus", Location.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MAcon.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Production has begun");
            }
```

could someone help me as of now, every cell in column 4 changes and I'm not sure what I've done wrong

Comment: Your command says “set these columns on every row to these values.” You probably wanted a WHERE clause somewhere?

Comment: You should avoid `.AddWithValue()` & use `.Parameters.Add`. As it stands your passing a *value* of `OleDbType.Integer` which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Customer Orders] SET 
[OrderStatus] = (@OrderStatus), [OrderID]= @OrderId", MAcon);
```

Needs a `WHERE` clause.

Based on your description in the question, possibly:

```
WHERE column1 = labelContent
```